# using EmbeddedGraphDatabase with Jetty

Tags: dependency-injection, neo4j

I would like to use neo4j's embedded db on my web app.
Unfortunately I cannot use Spring.
Instead of instantiating a new db on each call, I'd rather inject a singleton.
How do I achieve this on Jetty ?

many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you are looking for, but I think you could inject a Neo4j instance into your servlet as a singleton via the servlets context?